# Make menu items open in new tab/page

Tags: menus

How do I make menu items open in a new tab/page instead of replacing 
the current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to Appearance > Menu
- click screen options (near top of page)
- tick "Link target"

Now, when you click a menu item drop down, you can choose what the link target is (you want to choose New window or tab)

Answer (score 0):

Admin > Appearance > Menus > Screen Options (Top right of the screen)
Add a check to Link Target

Now you can set the Link target for your menus.

Comment: Randomly chose anu for the checkmark, but thanks.